# CSS translate3d

Tags: css, transform, css-transforms

Ive been searching th internet for a few hours now and I cant fins a solution for what I would like to do.

on the child I have:

```
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  color: #3c4a50;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,93px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,93px,0);
```

And on hover I have:

```
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

What this is doing is starting the Y axis from the top and pushing it down 93px.

I need that to be reversed and make it so it reveals 93px on the bottom. So I need it to start at the bottom and pull up vs starting at the top and pushing down.

I didnt go into detail with html because I didnt think it would matter for this. if its needed let me know.

I have found things saying use:

```
transform-origin: center bottom;
```

However this I have not been able to get to work.

Any help is appreciated, as always.

Cheers

**UPDATE**

Testing here to see if its working properly

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100%;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  background: red;
  color: #3c4a50;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-93px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,-93px,0);
}


.child:hover{
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0px,0);
  bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 ways, with position `bottom` and with `flex`.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -93px, 0);
  transition:.3s;
}


.child:hover{
  transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason that wont work is because the Height is set to 100%. Or at least as far as I cant tell. I have made edits to the post to sow you the exact css. I tried to implement what you posted and its the same as I tried before unfortunately. The -93 is still pulling from the top. I need to make the 0 of the Y axis start at the bottom and expose just 93px of the child.

Comment: Essentially instead of 0 for the Y on hover id like to make it so I have to use 100%. Currently if I use 100% on the non hover of the child it ppushes it all the way down. So I need to reverse the Y or at least appear to. The reason I am trying to achieve this is for global CSS reasons. I could figure it out in px for each div that has different sizes. Imagine 1 div on the page is 500px tall and another is only 200px tall. If I can figue out how to reveal it from the bottom instead of pushing down from the top i can keep it global. Does that make sense?

Comment: Now you are exactly where I am. So we need to exactly reverse what you have in the new edit. I apologize for not putting html I should have, I honestly didnt think it would be needed. 

So currently your new edit is hiding 93px on the top. When we hover it slides down the that 93px. We need to hide all but 93px on the bottom. So the exact reverse. It will slide up and reveal the rest.

Comment: This is what I thought using `transform-origin: center bottom;` was supposed to do. I thought that meant it would switch the anchor from the top to the bottom. And give me the exact reverse of your new edit.

Comment: Edited again, now ti goes bottom -100%, it can also be done with top:100%;

Comment: It seems to be right. I see your is. Im trying to implement. Right now taking your additions. Which is genius btw. I never thought of the negative bottom. However when I hover my animation is still sliding in from the top instead of sliding up. As I said I see your example working properly however.

Comment: Hey @Ervald. I updated, could you take a look at the odd behavior I have happening. I looked at your example which is properly working btw. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your transition should be `transition: 0.35s;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115612/discussion-between-ervald-and-sean).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look into what the transition: transform was doing. But you were correct on all accounts. Thank you so much for your help. Cheers